# Read large text file in java, infeasible?

Tags: java, file-io

I'm using the following method to read a file into a `JTextArea`:

```
public void readFile(File file) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException,
                                       java.io.IOException {
   if(file == null) return;
   jTextArea1.setText("");
   try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
     String line = "";
     while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
         jTextArea.append(line + "\n");
     }
   }
}
```

It works OK with a normal-sized file (a few hundred kilobytes), but when I tested a 30000-line file of 42 MB that Notepad can open in about 5 seconds, my file reader took forever. I couldn't wait for it to finish; I had waited for about 15-20 minutes and it was still working consuming 30% of my CPU usage.

Could you please give me a solution for this? I'm handling with text files only, not binary files, and all I know is using `BufferedReader` is the best.

Comment: The nio file handling APIs would be better suited here

Comment: if you want really fast reading/ writing look at [java nio package][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599711/understanding-java-nio-concepts

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely not in the file reading but the processing. Repeated calls to `append` are likely to be very inefficient with large datasets.

Consider using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString%28%29). This class is designed for quickly creating long strings from parts (on a single thread; see [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) for a multi-threaded counterpart).

```
if(file == null) return;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
jTextArea1.setText("");
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
    String line = "";
    while((line==reader.readLine())!=null){
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append('\n');
    }
    jTextArea1.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

As suggested in the comments, you may wish to perform this action in a new thread so the user doesn't think your program has frozen.

Comment: If you expect to handle this large files, you might want to consider the following. Move the 'read file and fill `JTextArea` logic into a seperate thread. Your UI could display a text like 'Please wait while loading the file', informing the user that something is being done although they cannot see the results yet.

Comment: @bdares that's another problem, yes, but I'm not aware of any remedies for that.

Comment: @mthmulders Yes, true; even better, use a SwingWorker or similar

Comment: @WChargin Have you tried this first? I tried using StringBuilder and there is likely no change in how long it loads, too slow, I tested with a file of 700KB and it took about 20 seconds, I also tried reading that file in C# and it took only about 10 seconds. The problem is display text in JTextArea, if loading file into StringBuilder only, it works rather fast. This also happens when coding in C#, loading file is in fact very fast, but displaying the content in a TextBox or RichTextBox took a lot of time... Plus, you have a typo between 'line' and 'reader.readLine()', it's '=' not '=='.Thanks!